# what is wrong with my Android Studio code? xml works fine kt not

Tags: android, xml

So I am building an App for a friend and my just wont work. My xml code works with the exception of unexpected end of file but it still works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextColumnName"
        android:layout_width="387dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Schülername eingeben"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddColumn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Schüler hinzufügen" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But my ketlin code has 12 problems, almost all of them being "Unresolved reference: something" I marked the specific unresolved...words

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.**recyclerview***.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.**recyclerview**.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: **RecyclerView**
    private lateinit var adapter: **MyAdapter**
    private lateinit var layoutManager: **LinearLayoutManager**

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Finde die Views aus dem Layout
        val editTextColumnName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextColumnName)
        val buttonAddColumn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAddColumn)

        // RecyclerView und Adapter initialisieren
>       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.**recyclerView**)
        layoutManager = **LinearLayoutManager**(this)
>       recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        adapter = **MyAdapter**()
>       recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        // Klick-Listener für den Button hinzufügen
        buttonAddColumn.setOnClickListener {
            val columnName = editTextColumnName.text.toString().trim()
            if (columnName.isNotEmpty()) {
                // Spalte hinzufügen
                adapter.addColumn(columnName)
                // Feld leeren
                editTextColumnName.text.clear()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The lines that are marked as quotes aren't an unresolved refernce but other issues being

1.
`` Not enough information to infer type variable T & `@layout/activity_main` does not contain a declaration with id `recyclerView` ``

2.
`Variable ecpected`

4.
`Variable expected`

I tried to resolve the problem with ChatGPT because i'm fairly new to ketlin and Android Studio but that didn't work.   I just have to add more characters I don't know what else to write if someone still has a question just ask.

Comment: In order for it to work, you need `RecyclerView` in your XML with the following XML attribute: `android:id="@+id/buttonAddColumn"`

Comment: where exactly do I implement it in the XML? I tried it I feel like everywhere I don't get it

Comment: I suggest you follow the lessons here: https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/unit-2